# Characters and decomposition

Tags: representation-theory, characters

[image]

This is taken from Linear representations of finite groups by J.P.Serre, page 16.
My query is :

1.Does distinct irreducible characters imply non-isomorphic?

2.Here in the decomposition of $V$, $W_{i}$ is non-isomorphic to $W_{j}$ for $i\ne j$ right?

Comment: 1. Yes. Conjugate matrices share the same trace, so  isomorphic representations share the same character. 2. Yes.

Comment: Tip: Photos are non-searchable (when given a string as input), so we strongly advice users to type in the text rather than posting scanned shortish passages. This is not always feasible, so use your judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character $\chi: G \to \mathbb{C}$ of a $G$-representations is always constant on conjugacy classes, that means $$\forall g,h \in G:  \chi(hgh^{-1})=\chi(g)$$

So all the characters lie in the space $T = \{ \chi: G \to \mathbb{C}: \chi  \text{ constant on conjugacy classes}\}$. The number of conjugacy classes of $G$ is therefore the dimension of $T$.

One can show that the irreducible characters are linear independent and that the number of simple $G$-modules is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$, so the irreducible characters are a basis of $T$. We get the following:

> Let $V, W$ be $G$-modules with representations $D_v: G \to GL(V), D_w: G \to GL(W)$ and characters $\chi_V, \chi_W: G \to \mathbb{C}$, then
>
> $$V \simeq W \Leftrightarrow \chi_V = \chi_W$$

While the direction $\Rightarrow$ is simple (see the comments), the $\Leftarrow$ is also not difficult now:

Using the notation above, let $\chi_V = \chi_W$. According to Maschke and Schur there is a unique decomposition of $V$ and $W$ into the simple $G$-modules $W_1, ..., W_r$:

$V = m_1 W_1 \oplus ... \oplus m_r W_r$

$W = m'_1 W_1 \oplus ... \oplus m_r' W_r$

where the $m_i$'s and the $m'_i$'s are the multiplicities, means $m_i W_i = W_i \oplus ... \oplus W_i$ ($m_i$ times).

$\chi_v = \chi_w \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^r m_i \chi_{W_i} = \sum_{i=1}^r m'_i \chi_{W_i} \Rightarrow m_i = m'_i f.a. i=1,...,r \Rightarrow V \simeq W$,

where the secound implication follows from the linear independence of the irreducible characters.

Comment: I am not sure how easy it would be to fill out the details of doing things in precisely the order presented here. At least I find it easier to show independence of the characters using the inner product, and then the fact that they span the class functions is not necessary for this statement (that they really do span is then a matter of studying the center of the group algebra).